# Programmatically check if an Activity is declared in the AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: java, android

I want to check if an activity is declared in the app's manifest.

Some ads platform, like MMedia, Admob, etc need concret activities to be declared in your manifest. I want to automate a test that checks if those activities has been declared. Some of this libraries throws an exception if you forget to declare the activities, other just do not work.

For example, checking if the activity `com.google.ads.AdActivity` is in my manifest

Thanks

Comment: I am not entirely sure why do you need it. Could you elaborate it a little bit?

Comment: Updated the question please check it

Comment: is that only for the sake of testing?

Comment: Yest, just tests and avoid exceptions in runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) contains all information of declared services, activities etc.

Use [`getInstalledPackages()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstalledPackages%28int%29) with the `GET_ACTIVITIES` flag.

If it's not in there, it's not declared.

Example:

```
List<PackageInfo> pInfos = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
for (PackageInfo pInfo : pInfos) {
  ActivityInfo[] aInfos = pInfo.activities;
  if (aInfos != null) {
    for (ActivityInfo activityInfo : aInfos) {
      Log.i("ACT", activityInfo.name);
      // do whatever else you like... 
    }
  }
}
```

You can also use packageinfo:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
PackageInfo packageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(this.getPackageName(), 0);

packageInfo.activities // contains a list of all your activity tags under <application>,
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, this code return all the activities declared by all the applications, how can I retrieve only those declared by my app?

Comment: Read the PackageManager documentation, you know know what to use it has multiple methods you can use. For example if `getPackageArchiveInfo()`.  You can always attempt to just start an activity (you want to check), and catch the Exception. If it throws the undeclared, you know.